# AntD Upload need to validate before crop image

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to upload square images and I want to validate the image type. I have the following code. this code validates after the image is cropped. But I want to validate before the image load to crop in the modal.

AntD component

```
<ImgCrop rotate>
                  <Upload
                    listType="picture-card"
                    customRequest={onFileChange}
                    fileList={fileList}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onPreview={onPreview}
                    beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
                    maxCount={1}
                    onRemove={onRemove}
                  >
                    {fileList.length < 1 && "+ Upload"}
                  </Upload>
</ImgCrop>
```

Validation function

```
function beforeUpload(file) {
const isJpgOrPng = file.type === "image/jpeg" || file.type === "image/png";
if (!isJpgOrPng) {
  message.error("You can only upload JPG/PNG file!");
}
const isLt2M = file.size / 1024 / 1024 < 2;
if (!isLt2M) {
  message.error("Image must smaller than 2MB!");
}
return isJpgOrPng && isLt2M;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should validate image with props beforeCrop in [ImgCrop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/antd-img-crop)

beforeCrop: Call before modal open, if return false, it'll not open